# a matrix file load into Perl

Tags: perl, file-upload, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have a square matrix file, and I want to load it into Perl. I want to operate like 2 dimensional array which in C is like matrix[14][50], and then it goes directly to row 14 column 50. Is there a way to do this?

And can I modify the input file directly or I have to load it into a variable, do the operation and then write it out?

Comment: sorry it should go to row 15 column51

Comment: What does this have to do with perl?

Comment: Use the `edit` button to change the information in your question, do not add it in the comments.

Comment: a typo, sorry，load into Perl actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a module which is likely able to do what you need. [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV). It creates a magical array of arrayrefs (a Perl 2D array), which allows row and element r/w access to a file. Depending on your column separator you might need to adjust the options (CSV is default).

Answer (score 0):

It works very similarly with different syntax.

```
>matrix <- array(1:10000, dim=c(100,100)) #50 X 50 matrix
>somevariable <- matrix[14,51] #somevariable will now be 5014
```

Turn this into a R script

and call it from perl such as

```
my $var = `rscript arguments`; # $var is now the output of your rscript
```

Comment: good respond but it's my fault that I want to achieve that in perl. being busy switch between R and Perl